# Problem with misunderstanding curve function

Tags: r

I define a function f as :

```
f <- function(x){
  if (x < 0) {
    x^3-x^2+4
  } else {
    -4*x+2
  }
}
```

and now i want to draw it with curve function for example on interval [-100,100].

So i write

```
curve(f,from=-100,to=100)
```

And i only get the function x^3-x^2+4 on interval [-100,100]

Why i don't get my function -4x+2 on interval [0,100] ?

When i want to draw function f for example on interval [3,4] it show's me a good function. It seem's to be a problem when it has to draw two functions in a one graph.

Comment: Welp, there is a warning message saying *"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"* - did you try to Google that? In other words, `if` isn't vectrized. Try `f <- function(x) ifelse(x<0, x^3-x^2+4, -4*x+2)` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much it's working !! But why i have vertical line in discontinuous point ?

Comment: I see this when i draw graph on a small interval, for example [-1,1]